# Ubuntu 20.10 Sinhala wijesekara keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus

I'm from Sri Lanka, I switched to Ubuntu 20.10 from Windows 10.

I want to type my language, Sinhala with Unicode. the standard layout for this is a layout called "Wijesekara". I can't find this layout in keyboard layout.

I don't wanna go back to Windows: how can I install the Sinhala keybord layout on my pc?

This layout is available during the installation:
[image: screen 1]

Comment: Install the `ibus-m17n` package and relogin. After that you ought to find it.

Comment: hi! Thank you. This works for me